# Why is Italiae used rather than Italis in the phrase "In hortis Italiae"?

Tags: grammar-choice, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In the Grammatica Latina at the end of Cap. V of LLPSI Pars I, Ørberg has the following examples for singular and plural ablative of each gender:

> [A] Masculinum.   In horto Iulii. In hortis Italiae.
>
> [B] Femininum.   In villa Iulii. In villis Romanis.
>
> [C] Neutrum.   In oppido Tusculo. In oppidis Graecis.

In the plural masculine ablative example, why is *Italiae* used rather than *Italis* when *Graecis* is used with the neuter example? I'm assuming *Italiae* is the nominative plural of the noun, *Italia*, but *Graecis* is the ablative plural of the noun *Graecus*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Graecus, -a, -um* is an adjective “Greek”, put in the ablative plural *Graecis* to agree with the ablative plural noun *oppidis*: “In (the) Greek towns.”

*Italia* is a noun “Italy”; *Italiae* is the genitive singular: “In (the) gardens of Italy.” Genitive nouns don’t show any agreement in Latin, so only *hortis* is marked for ablative plural. The same goes for “In horto Julii” “In (the) garden of Julius”.

The ablative plural adjective *Italis* (a form of the adjective *Italus, -a, -um*) would also be grammatical; I’m not sure why a genitive vs. an adjective would be used.

(In oppido Tusculo is a third construction, an apposition where both the common noun and the proper noun are inflected for the appropriate case, rather than one being inflected in agreement with the other. In this case they happen to have the same gender and number but some towns have feminine or plural names in Latin: e.g. *in oppido Athenis* literally “in (the) town Athens” meaning “in the town of Athens.”)

Comment: I believe the adjective *Italus* is very uncommon in prose. The ordinary adjective is *Italicus*. But, as you say, there is no real reason why Ørberg should have used *Italiae* rather than *Italicis*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was expecting that each example would use adjectives, and was scratching my head as to why the first example didn't follow the same pattern as the others. I suppose this is Ørberg slyly throwing in other structures. I understood the meaning of each in general, but not the distinction of each type.